# mongo repository query for array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using MongoRepository query instead of MongoTemplate for querying list of objects.Below is the sample mongo json values.

```
    {  
   "host":[  
      {  
         "user":"username",
         "pass":"password"
      },
      {  
         "user":"username1",
         "pass":"password"
      }
   ]
}

{  
   "host":[  
      {  
         "user":"username",
         "pass":"password123"
      },
      {  
         "user":"username123",
         "pass":"password"
      }
   ]
}
```

Need to get list of host Object based on username and password query.
Below is my query

```
@Query("{'host.user' : { $in : ?0 }, 'host.pass' : { $in : ?1 }}")
public List<Host> getListofHost(String username,String password);
```

But Actually it is listing all host since username and password is present in list of host,Is there a way to get Actual List of host getListofHost("username","password") and it should return only

```
"host":[  
  {  
     "user":"username",
     "pass":"password"
  },
  {  
     "user":"username1",
     "pass":"password"
  }
]
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why don't you handle this at your logic instead of try to achieve with database query?

Comment: please add the value of the parameters too

Comment: Actually I found the answer,we can do by Monogo Repository query by 
    @Query("{'host' : {'$elemMatch': {'user':?0, 'pass': ?1}}}) public List<Host> getListofHost(String username,String password);